# Event dispatch thread exception?

Tags: java, eclipse

Here is my code, I run it on eclipse and it displays the frame the button and the field, using the button should return the value of the equation typed in the field fe. When i put 2+2 in the field and click "oblicz" it should return 4 but it does not, and it drops some weird exception. Am I missing something?

```
    static JTextField pole1;

    public static void main(String[]args)            
    {


        JFrame frame = new JFrame("applet 1.0");
        frame.setSize(700, 600);                    
        frame.setLocation(300, 100);                
        frame.setResizable(false);                    
        frame.setLayout(null);                        
        frame.setVisible(true);

        // pole

        pole1 = new JTextField();          
        pole1.setBounds(10, 10, 230, 50);              
        Font F1 = new Font("Comic Sans",Font.BOLD,20);  
        pole1.setFont(F1);  
        pole1.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);                                        
        frame.add(pole1);                                

       // button

        JButton button = new JButton("oblicz");  
        button.setBounds(10, 80, 100, 70);                
        button.setBorder(null);                            
        frame.add(button);

        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0)
            {
                {
                    String str = pole1.getText();

                    ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
                    ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
                    String foo = str;
                    try
                        {
                        pole1.setText(String.valueOf(engine.eval(foo)));
                        }
                        catch (ScriptExecption e)
                        {

                        }

                }

            }
     });
```

Comment: How about providing us with that "weird" exception + stack trace?

Comment: And the code.. here, in the question, not as a link to some other site.

Comment: Sorry, im begginer - its my first question here

Comment: No worries, we are all learning. I updated your question so the code is there. We still need the stack trace though.

Comment: Can you please explain me how can I get it? Im using eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Your code as written worked for me.

However, I made some changes to your code to use Swing more effectively.

[image: Applet GUI]

1. I removed all the code from the main method and replaced it with a call to the SwingUtilities invokeLater method.  The invokeLater method puts the creation and use of the Swing components on the [Event Dispatch thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).  Oracle and I demand that all Swing applications start on the Event Dispatch thread.
2. I put the JTextField and JButton on a JPanel.  Do not add Swing components other than JPanel or other panel type components to a JFrame.
3. I separated the creation of a JFrame from the creation of a JPanel.  Divide and conquer.  Separation of concerns makes the code easier to read and test.
4. I created the JPanel and JFrame before I made it visible.  Call the JFrame methods in the order I posted.
5. I removed the null layout and the absolute positioning of the Swing components.  Swing was designed to be used with [Swing layout managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).  Learn them.  Use them.
6. I used a couple of empty JPanel borders to add some white space around the components.
7. I fixed some syntax problem in your action listener.  In my Eclipse IDE, I deleted your try / catch block and let Eclipse generate the try / catch block.  I added a printStackTrace method call so that any exception would print out as a stack trace.

Here's the code.

```
package com.ggl.testing;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptException;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class JavascriptCalculator implements Runnable {

    private JButton button;

    private JTextField pole1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new JavascriptCalculator());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Applet 1.0");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(createPanel());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.getRootPane().setDefaultButton(button);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        // pole

        JPanel polePanel = new JPanel();
        polePanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 0, 10, 0));

        pole1 = new JTextField(20);
        Font f1 = new Font("Comic Sans", Font.BOLD, 20);
        pole1.setFont(f1);
        pole1.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);
        polePanel.add(pole1);

        panel.add(polePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        // button

        button = new JButton("oblicz");
        panel.add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                String str = pole1.getText().trim();

                ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
                ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
                String foo = str;

                try {
                    pole1.setText(String.valueOf(engine.eval(foo)));
                } catch (ScriptException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        return panel;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Gilbert!! And those tips... I love them!
Have a great day

Comment: When I try to run this on my pc it returns error:
Error: Could not find or load main class programy.okno1

Comment: it isnt, and thats why I tried to create entirely new java package and even then it returns the same error, damn its frustrating